# Contents of the cell next to it in another worksheet

Tags: excel

I'm getting the highest value between column B.

`=MÁXIMO(Plan1!B2:B4)`

I need to bring in another cell the content that is next to the column with the highest value

[image]

Comment: `Index/Match`? What have you tried? What data do you want to return, `Data 2`?

Comment: `Data 2?` - Yes

Answer (score 1):

This should work I believe :

```
=Index(a2:a4,match(max(b2:b4),b2:b4,0)
```